# Probabilty question on correct option

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I was asked this question in an interview of data science and I found it hard to find the right approach . Kindly help .

Below is the question:

Check the following statements from 1-3 , each statement could either be True or False .

Statement 1:    Customer has high LTV (Premium)
Statement 2:    Customer had churned in past 
Statement 3:    Customer was referred from third party.

Suppose I know that statement 2 is True  with 60% confidence . Statement 3 is false with 70% confidence and statement 1 is true with 80% confidence , then what is the probability that option 1 is correct (only statement 1 and statement 2 are correct?)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It depends a lot on if these probabilities are dependent or independent. I interpret the claim that statement 3 is false with 70% confidence as meaning 'only 30% of all customers are referred by a third party'. But is this percentage still 30% when we look at all customers with high LTV (whatever that is)? Or could the percentage in that group be higher or lower? In that case you cannot answer the question without knowing more about how much higher or lower...

Comment: Thanks @Vincent for replying , I was told all the 3 statements are independent . The Interpretation of statement 3 being false with  70% confidence , is the user based on heuristic /past knowledge knows this statement is false and scores his confidence at 70% for this .

Comment: Then I recommend drawing a tree diagram. If you google tree diagram and probability you find a lot of explainer

Comment: Thankyou @Vincent , Tree diagram helped solved this problem . Thanks for your insights and approach .

Comment: you're welcome!